# Override path in docker image

Tags: docker

I've a docker image for which I want to change the default config file.

The problem is that this config file contains the path to a program contained in the image and I'm not sure how to modify this.

```
docker run --rm -u `id -u \`whoami\`` -v /my/path/file:/data/ -t docker/program -i input -r -o output -c config.file
```

config.file
program=/path/to/program/

Comment: Are you trying to use environment-specific config files? Curious what you're actually trying to do -- is it possible to pass `/path/to/program/` as an environment variable instead?

Comment: The thing is that the dependency this program uses is not installed at my computer but inside the docker image.